# How to load external CDN Script into WebView (React Native)

Tags: react-native

My goal is to be able to load the script below into a react Native WebView

```
<script src="https://paddle.test.com/paddle/paddle.js">
```

This is a CDN for a payment processor but it's not loading

Code for webview

```
<WebView
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
  source={{ html: '<script src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">Paddle.Setup({ vendor: 12345 });</script><a href="#!" class="paddle_button" data-product="12345" data-email="name@email.com">Buy now</a><h1>This is a static HTML source!</h1>' }}
/>
```

The webview is showing the text and button but no styling and no JS

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: maybe try to make the `html` full? like adding the <html> tag etc., not sure if this will work though

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't load